Why is my Lenovo ThinkPad running Ubuntu using the e1000e Ethernet driver?
I have a brand new ThinkPad E16 Gen 2 laptop, running Ubuntu 24.01.1 LTS. I have recently had problems with suspend and I narrowed it down to the Wake on LAN functionality of my LAN adapter.
While resolving that, I've noticed that I'm running the e1000e driver, which to my understanding is ancient and is only really used in VMs where there's no better option.
Why is it choosing to use e1000e? I'd have expected a more modern driver to be used.
I'm not sure how to even debug this or what to try, nor which driver it should be using instead. So even general advice would be appreciated.
Dry details:
❯ cat /etc/*release* | grep PRETTY_NAM
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"

❯ sudo dmidecode -s system-version 
ThinkPad E16 Gen 2

❯ uname -r        
6.8.0-45-generic

❯ lspci -nnk | grep -i ethernet -A3
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:550b] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:50e1]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

For reference, running that last command on a different (Mint) laptop I have gave me this output, which is closer to what I expect:
❯ lspci -nnk | grep -i ethernet -A3
3d:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 16)
  DeviceName: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:878a]
  Kernel driver in use: r8169
  Kernel modules: r8169


Its not a default install but lshw is a VERY nice resource for working out your network hardware. If its installed - try lshw -c network


For reference, running that last command on a different (Mint) laptop I have gave me this output, which is closer to what I expect:

To put it simply, you're using the e1000e driver because your laptop physically has an Intel Ethernet interface.¹ The other laptop is using the r8169 driver because it has a Realtek Ethernet chip. You don't have free choice of the driver – you use whatever driver is needed for the physical hardware that's in the laptop.
Even in virtual machines, you don't actually choose the driver as such; you tell the hypervisor what kind of chip to emulate (e.g. you make the VM have an emulated RTL8168) and the driver necessarily follows from that.

While resolving that, I've noticed that I'm running the e1000e driver, which to my understanding is ancient and is only really used in VMs where there's no better option.

No. It's still the standard driver for Intel's embedded Gigabit Ethernet NICs, e.g. the entirety of the Intel I219 series that is found in modern desktops or laptops; especially the vPro ones (AMT/vPro requires the NIC to be part of the CPU).
Gigabit Ethernet is itself fairly old technology and so the hardware hasn't changed much – a new I219 still uses nearly the same interface to the host OS as an older Intel 82573, which allows the same driver to support it with minimal changes. Why re-do it differently and require a brand new driver if the existing interface meets the requirements?
In fact, the same goes for the Realtek r8169 driver: it was originally written in 2002, which makes it only three years younger than e1000e – but still more than two decades old by now.
But what makes both of these drivers "second tier" in VMs has little to do with the quality of the drivers themselves – it is more generally because they require the hypervisor to emulate the behavior of a physical device, which is always less efficient than VirtIO or another virtual-by-design device due to the differences in how e.g. memory space is set up.

¹ More specifically, it has Intel I219-V (version 18) as part of the Meteor Lake CPU/chipset. The -V indicates it's a vPro version, and vPro indeed only works with an Ethernet interface that's part of the same CPU. Your other laptop doesn't have vPro, so it can use any external part for Ethernet.

It would appear that ChatGPT has misled me :D It told me that 8086:550b was from the I225-LM family (which is 2.5Gbps) rather than I219 (Which is Gigabit), and I did not bother to verify. Thank you for the detailed answer! Here's my daily lesson to not take what LLMs say for granted <3

Well, the e1000e hw.h (updated by Intel themselves) definitely has 0x550b listed as an I219 (E1000_DEV_ID_PCH_MTP_I219_V18). For I225 it would be the igc driver, which has a similar-looking 0x5502 among its supported devices.

It's important to note the last e: e1000 supports the conventional PCI chips (which are ancient at this point) while e1000e supports PCIe models, which range from old to current.

@Madara'sGhost perhaps chatgpt isn't a good resource for anything technical.

chatgpt isn't a good resource, period

To be fair, ChatGPT did help me perfectly with uncovering my WoL issue that caused suspend to not work, and it even told me that it's likely that e1000e is the correct driver for me. I asked anyways because actual experts, but it still did a fairly good job.
